# How to close timeline window

Tags: timeline

I accidentally open the second timeline widow. What's worst it is moving simultaneously with the properties tab. My question is - does anyone know how can I close this window. Here you is what my problem looks like

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you grab the bottom corner of the top window you collapse the top timeline and you get rid of your 2 problems:

[image]

I may be wrong but for the moment it looks like if you have sticking windows, you can only get rid of them with the creation of a new one (or directly collapsing 2 windows but you'll need to recreate the one you had):

[image]